# Swift Decodable Class does not conform

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to Swift and am having a spot of bother with a decodable class.
I am receiving an error on this class : Type 'VoucherCode' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

I have exactly the same syntax in another project without error which came from a tutorial.

Without the published line, the class works and is decoded from relevant json.

What am I missing please?

```
import Foundation

class VoucherCode: Decodable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {

@Published var logoData: Data?

var id:UUID?
var title: String?
var voucherCode: String?
var details: String?
var logo: String?
var url: String?
var termsAndConditions: String?
var highlight: String?
var whoFor:[String]?



func getLogoData() {
    guard logo != nil else {
        return
    }
    
    if let url = URL(string: logo!) {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.logoData = data!
                }
            }
        }
        
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
}
```

A similar class (which works) from a CodeWithChris lesson. There is no error and it works.

[image: a working class]

Comment: For a type to automatically conform to `Decodable`, all of the variables will also need to be `Decodable`. The error is basically telling you that the type `Published<Data?>` does not conform to `Decodable`. You could manually implement `init(from decoder: Decoder)` though on `VoucherCode` to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your class:

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, title, voucherCode, details, logo, url, termsAndConditions, highlight, whoFor
}
```

this will exclude logoData from the decodable and make VoucherCode Decodable.